# Make circular photos downloaded from google (google places, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, google-places-api

I'm working with google places and i have a VC with a tableView where i downloaded nearby places from the user position and in each cell of the tableView i add the information of the place and the photo of it. I created a custom class to make the photo circular

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundImage: UIImageView {



    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

}
```

but the problem is that i download the photos of the places with this class

```
import UIKit

private let widthKey = "width"
private let heightKey = "height"
private let photoReferenceKey = "photo_reference"


class QPhoto: NSObject {


        var width: Int?
        var height: Int?
        var photoRef: String?



        init(photoInfo: [String:Any]) {
            height = photoInfo[heightKey] as? Int
            width = photoInfo[widthKey] as? Int
            photoRef = photoInfo[photoReferenceKey] as? String
        }

        func getPhotoURL(maxWidth:Int) -> URL? {
            if let ref = self.photoRef {
                return NearbyPlaces.googlePhotoURL(photoReference: ref, maxWidth: maxWidth)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
```

and i would like to know how can i adjust it, because with this class the photos that i download even though i put the `RoundImage` class at the imageview in the storyboard are always square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `clipsToBounds` to `true`.  You can do that when you set the `cornerRadius`:

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```